# error on testing entity framework 5 method from test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5

I've created VS 2013 web api project
I've added EF 5 data model and generate code in this project
I've written a method to insert data using EF 5
I've created VS 2013 Test project in the same solution and added reference of web api project
Written a simple test method, when executing this method I was getting error that no connection string found in the config file, so I added connection string in the Test project's config file.

after that I got following error:

> Model.MyModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider
>   found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the
>   'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See

Then I added entityFramework section to my test project

Now I am getting the following error

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

this error occurs on the following line

```
using (var dbcontext = new MyEntity())
```

Now how to resolve this , I couldn't found System.Data.SqlClient Assembly

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730568) You need to add below lines of code in your application :-

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    { 
        SetProviderServices( 
            SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, 
            SqlCeProviderServices.Instance); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't have System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact, I am still using EF 5

Comment: shu neel barobar vach

Comment: hehe han @DhavalPatel kai company ma chho tu?

Comment: @Neel: Investis at baroda

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Guys It was my mistake, Don't know how but two same connection string added into web api project's web.config file, I removed one of them and it worked very fine.

Comment: oh great..got to know something new :))